# Server Crashes randomly

Tags: windows-server-2008, citrix, server-crashes, bug

I have a problem, VM server 2008 R2 SP1 , running citrix is randomly crhasing, in event log I found following:

The computer has rebooted from a bugcheck. The bugcheck was: 0x0000003b (0x00000000c0000005, 0xfffff9600008744d, 0xfffff88007ba3de0, 0x0000000000000000)..

Any Idea what's causing it?
Here is results from debug:

here is info from Bugcehck:  Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *

---

SYSTEM_SERVICE_EXCEPTION (3b)
An exception happened while executing a system service routine.
Arguments:
Arg1: 00000000c0000005, Exception code that caused the bugcheck
Arg2: fffff9600008744d, Address of the instruction which caused the bugcheck
Arg3: fffff88007ba3de0, Address of the context record for the exception that caused the bugcheck
Arg4: 0000000000000000, zero.

### Debugging Details:

Page 125923 not present in the dump file. Type ".hh dbgerr004" for details

EXCEPTION_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0xc0000005 - The instruction at 0x%08lx referenced memory at 0x%08lx. The memory could not be %s.

FAULTING_IP: 
win32k!xxxInternalInvalidate+7d
fffff960`0008744d f6473208        test    byte ptr [rdi+32h],8

CONTEXT:  fffff88007ba3de0 -- (.cxr 0xfffff88007ba3de0)
rax=0000000000000000 rbx=0000000000010485 rcx=0000000000000000
rdx=0000000000000b02 rsi=0000000000000000 rdi=0000000000000000
rip=fffff9600008744d rsp=fffff88007ba47c0 rbp=0000000000000000
 r8=0000000000010485  r9=0000000000000000 r10=fffff900000004c0
r11=fffff900c26eac30 r12=0000000000000000 r13=0000000000000001
r14=0000000000000000 r15=0000000000000000
iopl=0         nv up ei pl zr na po nc
cs=0010  ss=0018  ds=002b  es=002b  fs=0053  gs=002b             efl=00010246
win32k!xxxInternalInvalidate+0x7d:
fffff960`0008744d f6473208        test    byte ptr [rdi+32h],8 ds:002b:00000000`00000032=??
Resetting default scope

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  WIN7_DRIVER_FAULT

BUGCHECK_STR:  0x3B

PROCESS_NAME:  csrss.exe

CURRENT_IRQL:  0

LAST_CONTROL_TRANSFER:  from fffff960001351a2 to fffff9600008744d

STACK_TEXT:
fffff880`07ba47c0 fffff960`001351a2 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000040 fffffa80`0678d330 00000000`00000000 : win32k!xxxInternalInvalidate+0x7d
fffff880`07ba4840 fffff960`001352a2 : fffffa80`0678d330 00000000`00000000 fffff880`07ba4ca0 fffffa80`06109ab0 : win32k!xxxInternalUserChangeDisplaySettings+0x486
fffff880`07ba4900 fffff960`001330e3 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 fffff900`c0f9ead0 fffff900`00000040 : win32k!xxxUserChangeDisplaySettings+0x92
fffff880`07ba49f0 fffff960`00115cba : 00000000`00000001 00000000`00aff960 00000000`00000000 ffffffff`ffffffff : win32k!xxxRemoteReconnect+0x6d7
fffff880`07ba4bf0 fffff800`016d9ed3 : fffffa80`06f66b00 fffff880`07ba4ca0 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : win32k!NtUserCallOneParam+0x4e
fffff880`07ba4c20 000007fe`fd1b2aea : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : nt!KiSystemServiceCopyEnd+0x13
00000000`00aff918 00000000`00000000 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : 0x000007fe`fd1b2aea

FOLLOWUP_IP: 
win32k!xxxInternalInvalidate+7d
fffff960`0008744d f6473208        test    byte ptr [rdi+32h],8

SYMBOL_STACK_INDEX:  0

SYMBOL_NAME:  win32k!xxxInternalInvalidate+7d

FOLLOWUP_NAME:  MachineOwner

MODULE_NAME: win32k

IMAGE_NAME:  win32k.sys

DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  50e64bda

STACK_COMMAND:  .cxr 0xfffff88007ba3de0 ; kb

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  X64_0x3B_win32k!xxxInternalInvalidate+7d

BUCKET_ID:  X64_0x3B_win32k!xxxInternalInvalidate+7d

Followup: MachineOwner

Comment: [What diagnostic steps have you tried?](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/3608/how-can-i-ask-better-questions-on-server-fault) (A memory test would be a good start on physical hardware - probably less so for a VM though.) There's really no possible way for us to tell you what's wrong from just that error code. [Even Microsoft can't do that](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w7itprohardware/thread/d2eb62e3-46f7-4d94-8ff7-db0543855b56/)

Comment: here is info from Bugcehck:

Comment: you can't get root cause from the code but it gives you a direction. Off the top of my head ...0007b is a boot disk issue, this one (3b) is a system service error.

Comment: Just a tip to the OP: Be careful about sending full dump files to someone else for debugging. They can contain passwords and other sensitive information that was resident in memory when the server crashed.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to debug the dump file to determine what happened.  My wild guess is on a driver causing bad pages.  This post [HOW TO: Debug Memory Dumps (Figure out what is causing a BSOD)](http://forums.majorgeeks.com/showthread.php?t=35246) is a pretty good step by step guid to using dumpchk to see what caused the BSOD